# Can't run desktop python applications when switching out the default Python version

Tags: software-center, python, gwibber

I work on Google Appengine which requires Python 2.5. We all know that Python 2.5 is not supported by latest release of Ubuntu. Ubuntu programs such as Software Center and Gwibber are highly dependent on Python 2.7 as I have changed by default version of Python to Python 2.5 (I ve created a symbolic link to `/usr/bin/python` -> `/usr/bin/python2.5`).

Every time I get some sort of errors. Which includes- Software Center does not work, Update Manager does not work, unable to update Gwibber (even from command line. It gives me error that default version of python is not 2.7).

However I work on command line so this is not an issue for me but in order to stay updated everytime I need to change symbolic link. Is there any other solution for such problem?

Comment: Dude that thread is about installing Python 2.5 in Ubuntu.That's not my problem. Due to Python 2.5 lot of applications such as Software Center, Update Manager, Unity Dash and Gwibber are not working properly. As they need Python 2.7 as a default python. But as I work on App Engine I need Python 2.5 as default.

Comment: Does this question answer my question http://askubuntu.com/questions/48663/? My error log refers to python2.7 . I have 2.5 installed though. I haven't setup a symbolic link and python still points to the 2.7 version. Help will be upvoted!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to install it manually then install it somewhere in `/usr/local/` or `/opt` and use either the full path to the python binary in your programs or set `$PATH` so that is has the directory containing your python binary before the other directories and use the usual `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: thanks buddy for giving me hint. I forgot that I can actually start my app engine server by `$ python2.5 ~/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py [PATH TO MY PROJECT]` This command solves the problem.

Comment: I got the solution. All you have to do is to edit `dev_appserver.py` file. You have to change first line to `/user/bin/python2.5` from `/user/bin/python`. No need to create Symbolic Link n all.
Sorry for Posting it late ;)