# Software Sources requires GTK 2 and won't run on 11.04

Tags: 11.04, gtk

I was trying to access Settings in Update Manager to setup automatic updates. But the Settings Dialog does not pop up. Cannot Access Software Sources from the Ubuntu Software Center>Edit>Software Sources... either. When I try to run software sources from the terminal I get the following error.

```
$ sudo software-properties-gtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 26, in <module>
    gi.require_version('Gtk', '2.0')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 46, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace Gtk not available
```

I understand that the package is looking for GTK namespace and requires Gtk  version 2.0
Trying to check what version of GTK is installed, I run the following and get

```
$ apt-cache showpkg libgtk2.0-0 | more
Package: libgtk2.0-0
Versions: 
2.24.4-0ubuntu2 (/var/lib/apt/lists/Ubuntu%2011.04%20%5fNatty%20Narwhal%5f%20-%2
0Release%20i386%20(20110426)_dists_natty_main_binary-i386_Packages) (/var/lib/ap
t/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_natty_main_binary-i386_Packages) (/va
r/lib/dpkg/status)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/Ubuntu%2011.04%20%5fNatty%20Narwhal%5f
%20-%20Release%20i386%20(20110426)_dists_natty_main_binary-i386_Packages
                  MD5: 3ed10be69b676a812afff2c7fdaa4017
```

How do I get software sources to run?

**Update:**
Found a related question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45159).I have python2.5 installed, but haven't set up a symbolic link to it,  and the above log mentions python2.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and finally solved it! Just for the record, reinstalling the packages as stated above did not help. This is what I did.

According to the [pygi docs](https://live.gnome.org/PyGObject/IntrospectionPorting), if you type

```
python -c 'from gi.repository import Gtk; print Gtk'
```

you should get

```
<gi.module.DynamicModule 'Gtk' from '/usr/lib/girepository-1.0/Gtk-3.0.typelib'>
```

(Gtk-2.0 depending on which version you have installed. I have Gtk-2.0.)

This gave me the clue. The Gtk typelib was in fact there but I suspected there may be another `girepository-1.0` directory in my filesystem that was taking precedence. Using the `locate` command I found it in `/usr/local/lib` along with several `libgirepository-1.0*` libs. This directory did not contain the Gtk typelib. So I simply removed it along with the libraries and the problem is now solved.

Comment: I get `ERROR:root:Could not find any typelib for Gtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name Gtk`

Comment: That means that the Python module trying to load the Gtk module cannot find it in the current `girepository-1.0` directory, which assuming you installed the packages recommended by **jnv**, is apparently not in `/usr/lib/` as it should be. Use the `locate` command as I explained before. Prior to using it enter `sudo updatedb`.

Comment: @Markud locate girepository-1.0 gives a list of locations http://pastie.org/2267942

Comment: Well, the Gtk typelib is there. I recommend you delete the `libgirepository-1.0.*` libraries in `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: It runs! What was the problem with the `libgirepository-1.0.*` in the `/usr/local/lib` folder? Thank you.

Comment: Those libraries were present both in `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib`. The ones in the latter location were taking precedence but the typelibs are in `/usr/lib`. Glad it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Since software-properties is a Python application, it actually depends on package `gir1.2-gtk-2.0`. If you don't have this package installed, you have broken dependencies. Check it out using Synaptic.

Otherwise reinstallation of the affected packages may help:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gir1.2-gtk-2.0 python-software-properties software-properties-gtk
```

Comment: I still get the same error!

Answer (score 0):

ame as the above solution except I made a soft link in the /usr/local directory pointing to /usr/lib/girepository-1.0.  I also renamed the old directory.

ls -l

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4,0K loka  14 14:08 girepository-1.0_old

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    25 loka  14 14:10 girepository-1.0 -> /usr/lib/girepository-1.0

It wouldn't work otherwise.