# GNOME 3 on 11.04: Doesn't work. How to troubleshoot?

Tags: 11.04, gnome

I installed GNOME 3 on Natty, using the PPA and these [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3/28392#28392). I restarted and tried to log in using Gnome, only to be greeted by a

> Oh no! Something has gone wrong.
>   A problem has occurred and the system
>   can't recover. Please log out and try again.
>   Log out

It doesn't give any other details. Where can I access the log or know more about the error or How do I fix the problem?

Specs:
Aspire One ZG5
Ubuntu 11.04

**Update:**
I tried this from the instructions [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1749189)

```
cd ~/.config/autostart
nano gnome-shell.desktop
```

Then, in the editor, type this:

```
Code:
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=gnome-shell --replace
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=Gnome Shell
Name=Gnome Shell
Comment[en_US]=
Comment=
```

When I rebooted into GNOME, I did not get the error but I did not get anything else either. Even Unity and Unity 2D failed to load. So, I re-edited gnome-shell.desktop and removed all text. Now when I log in to GNOME, I get the wallpaper and nothing else. I can log in to Unity and Unity 2D though. Also, I have a problem with running [software-sources-gtk on the same system.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48663) Is it related?

How do I change my video drivers to open source ones? I did not install any drivers while installing Ubuntu, so the drivers are provided by Ubuntu.

Video driver:

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GME
>   Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)

After updating to GNOME 3, my system settings folder has changed. I do not have a Hardware Drivers option now. How do I update / change my video drivers?

Comment: What video driver? lspci | grep VGA

Comment: One thing you should consider is that GNOME 3 is likely to explode your system - it has a tendency to break multiple system items, and this has been documented in other questions relating to GNOME 3

Comment: @The Evil Phoenix, this is part of why when I tested GNOME 3 on Ubuntu 10.10, I always just built it myself from the official git repos using jhbuild. Much fewer problems that way. :)

Comment: @wojox 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GME Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)

Comment: @The Evil Am on a test system. It has already broken a few things I guess.

Comment: @wojox I uninstalled GNOME3 using http://www.ajopaul.com/2011/04/26/ubuntu-11-04-uninstall-gnome3-and-revert-to-gnome-2-x/ Guess GNOME 3 does not support Intel 945GME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a tty, stop gdm (sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop) (if you are using it) and start X (startx) from the tty. It may give you more info about what is happening. Probably it's a driver problem.
Another thing you could try is logging as a different (new) user. Maybe there is some config conflict around. If you are using ATI video card, then shift to open source drivers, because actually G3 is not compatible in almost every case with fglrx.

Comment: stopped gdm, started X server and got a "Could not load session gnome" pop up box. I should try open source video drivers? I am currently on  00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GME Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)

Comment: How do I go about changing my video drivers?